# ignore unnecessary new-line changes from git

Tags: git

Is there a way I can ignore all new line updates from a git commit?

I have a tool which unnecessarily removes new-lines from my files and after running it I have like hundreds of files changed which essentially only have new lines removed from them. I want to ignore such changes.

Comment: What do mean by "removes new-lines"? Do you mean it's removing blank lines? Removing just the last newline at the end of the file? Or is it actually *changing* newlines between LF and CRLF styles? Please clarify.

Comment: @Tushar do you mind voting up? looks like you marked it as answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand this [article](https://coderwall.com/p/crj69a/from-a-useless-git-diff-to-a-useful-one) you can only ignore it while making a diff but not for commiting. That would also not make a lot of sense, because what will be stored in the repo and what would happen if you made a pull afterwards?

What I like to do is making a pure cleanup commit, so the changes you really do to the code are separated.

For the diff it would be something like

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines [commit] ...
```

Comment: seems like this does not ignore new-lines

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not need a script at git already has some functionality for this built in when using a `.gitattributes` file

Check out [this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) GitHub Article on dealing with line endings

> `text eol=crlf`
>    - Git will always convert line endings to CRLF on checkout. You should use this for files that must keep CRLF endings, even on OSX or
>   Linux.
>
> `text eol=lf`
>    - Git will always convert line endings to LF on checkout. You should use this for files that must keep LF endings, even on Windows.

Comment: i do not think that is what he is asking, doesn´t he refer to blank lines being removed?

Comment: don't think so: 'new-lines'